# Block terminal input while running a terminal program

Tags: c++, unix, terminal

When I press enter while my terminal program runs, a new line is added. How can I disable this? I don't want to use ncurses. I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: Cut off the users hands?!

Comment: I think there's no way in standard c++. maybe you should use linux's API

Comment: You need to disable local echo on the terminal.

Comment: @ikh: I use ANSI codes to move the cursor, so something like that is okay, too!

Comment: @n.m: Something like this: ttynew.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; ? Can you elaborate a bit what it exactly does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up n.m's hint, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803703/the-meaning-of-disabling-local-echo-in-terminal) and came up with this:

```
static struct termios t;
tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &t);
t.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
```

This seems to block all input to the terminal.

Comment: You *probably* also want to set either non-canonical mode, or "raw" mode, and echo all normal (non-control) characters yourself. See `man termios`.