# How do I clear user input (cin) that occurred while the process was blocked?

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a C++ program that takes input from the user on `std::cin`. At some points it needs to call a function that opens a GUI window with which the user can interact. While this window is open, my application is blocked. I noticed that if the user types anything into my application's window while the other window is open, then nothing happens immediately, but when control returns to my application those keystrokes are all acted upon at once. This is not desirable. I would like for all keystrokes entered while the application is blocked to be ignored; alternatively, a way to discard them all upon the application regaining control, but retaining the capability to react to keystrokes that occur *after* that.

There are various questions on Stack Overflow that explain how to clear a line of input, but as far as I can tell they tend to assume things like "the unwanted input only lasts until the next newline character". In this case this might not be so, because the user could press enter several times while the application is blocked. I have tried a variety of methods (`getline()`, `get()`, `readsome()`, ...) but they generally seem not to detect when cin is temporarily exhausted. Rather, they wait for the user to continue supplying content for cin. For example, if I use `cin.ignore(n)`, then not only is everything typed while the GUI window was open ignored, but the program keeps waiting afterwards while the user types content until a total of `n` characters have been typed. That's not what I want - I want to ignore characters based on where *in time* they occurred, not where *in the input stream* they occur.

What is the idiom for "exhaust everything that's in cin *right now*, but then stop looking for more stuff"? I don't know what to search for to solve this.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233068/stdcin-empty-the-input-buffer-without-blocking), which might be similar and has an answer, but the answer asks for the use of `<termios.h>`, which isn't available on Windows.

Comment: This is an XY problem.  Solve the real issue, don't let your console go catatonic like this.  Start a thread and let *it* display the window.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to achieve what you are trying to do. You basically need to set the input stream to non-blocking state and keep reading as long as there are any characters.

`get()` and `getline()` will just block until there is enough input to satisfy the request. `readsome()` only deals with the stream's internal buffer and is only use to non-blockingly extract what was already read from the streams internal buffer.

On POSIX systems you'd just set the `O_NONBLOCK` with `fcntl()` and keep `read()`ing from file descriptor 0 until the read returns a value `<= 0` (if it is less than 0 there was an error; otherwise there is no input). Since the OS normally buffers input on a console, you'd also need to set the stream to non-canonical mode (using `tcsetattr()`). Once you are done you'd probably restore the original settings.

How to something similar on non-POSIX systems I don't know.